# What is the algebra generated by a set of functions?

Tags: general-topology

Well, consider $X$ a metric space, my main doubt is: What is the sub-algebra, of the algebra of continuous functions $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$, generated by a set $S$ of continuos functions?

Also: Let $E,F$ be two metric spaces. What is the algebra generated by the functions $(x,y)\to u(x)$ and $(x,y)\to v(y)$ where $u \in \mathcal{C}(E,\mathbb{R})$ and $v \in \mathcal{C}(F, \mathbb{R})$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is of course a subalgebra of $\mathcal C(X\times F,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. Thanks

Comment: $E,F$ are arbitrary metric spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subalgebra generated by $S$ is the smallest subalgebra that contains all elements of $S$. It can also be described as the intersection of all such subalgebras. Or as the set of all finite expressions formed from elements of $S$ under which the algebra must be closed, that is polynomial expressions in the generators.

With two functions defines on different metric spaces $E,F$, you may consider both as functions on $E\times F$.

Comment: So, Can I see the elements of the generated algebra like these sums $$ \sum_{i=1}^n u_i(x)v_i(y)\ ? $$

Comment: No. If you have one generator, your subalgebra contains all $P(g)$ for $P \in \Bbb K[X]$ but if you have two, it contains all $P(g_1,g_2)$ for $P \in \Bbb K[X,Y]$. It's not a one variable polynomial evaluated at one point depending on both, it's a two variable polynomial. So you have two sums. It'd be $\sum\limits_i \sum\limits_j \lambda_{i,j}u^iv^j$

Answer (score 0):

It is the algebra of the continuous functions from the product $E \times F$: for arbitrary product it would not hold (it would hold for coproduct), but since in the case of finitely many spaces the product and coproduct are isomorphic, in your case it holds.

Comment: I think you're being a bit too abstract for OP. I don't think he's ever heard 'coproduct' before ; and I'm saying this because I think I've done a lot of math but I still don't understand quite well what that means...

Comment: I've always found a good habit in mathematics showing the reason, why something is true, and this is the best way I can do. If you have never met category theory, it does not mean the others have not too..

Comment: I'm not suggesting your answer is bad, just that... you know. I've met category theory, but still, one can do a huge ton of algebra without ever dealing with coproducts. I do understand your point... but I hope you realize that category theory is usually never met for a big part of the math population. So in the point of view where you're trying to explain to someone you don't know some subject, it is okay to talk about what you know...

Comment: but I think it is a good assumption to guess that stuff like coproducts is unknown from the OP (unless the question is category-theory related of course); talking about it by saying stuff like 'if you've seen coproducts before, then in particular blablabla' would seem more user-friendly than just assuming that metric spaces and category theory should belong to the same topic in the way you wrote it... it feels kinda scary.